# Should be POSTing to a specific URL; instead, I see a GET to "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get

My POST looks like this:

```
var $postResults = $.ajax({
    url: "product/create/setting",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: { KEY: "datasource.name." + dsname, CLASS: dsclass, URL: dsurl },
        complete : function (xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                return xhr.responseText;
            }
});
return $postResults.responseText;
```

However, when I monitor what actually occurs, it shows a GET in the header, with a URL of "/" instead of "product/create/setting".

I showed it to a colleague and they said "It looks like the submit button is rejecting your reality and substituting its own submit function."

Any ideas on how to better troubleshoot this?

*EDIT*

Here's the full function (which is inside of $(document).ready)

```
function createEnvironmentPrep() {
    $('#createEnvironment').click(function () {
        $('div.zForms').html('');
        $('<div class="home-panel">' +
            '<h2 class="home-panel-header">Create New Environment</h2>' +
                '<form id="submitNewEnvironment">' +
                    '<label class="createlabel" for="envname">Name</label>' +
                    '<input id="envname" name="envname" type="text" size="25" required /><br />' +
                    '<label class="createlabel" for="envpath">Path</label>' +
                    '<input id="envpath" name="envpath" type="text" size="75" /><br />' +
                    '<input id="envsubmit" name="envsubmit" type="submit" class="submit" />' +
                '</form>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="returnmsg"></div>').appendTo('div.zForms');
        $('#envsubmit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $inputs = $('#submitNewEnvironment :input');
            var values = {};
            $inputs.each(function() {
                console.log($(this));
                values[this.name] = $(this).val();
            });
            var reqStatus = createEnvironment(values["envname"], values["envpath"]);
                if ( reqStatus === "Setting Updated" ) {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    $("#returnmsg")
                        .text(reqStatus)
                        .css("display", "block");
                    return this.revert;
                }
        });
    });
    function createEnvironment(envname, envpath) {
        var $postResults = $.ajax({
            url: "zforms/create/setting",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: { KEY: "report.environment." + envname, NAME: envname, PATH: envpath },
                complete : function (xhr, textStatus) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        return xhr.responseText;
                    }
        });
        return $postResults.responseText;
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, the inner assignment of a click function to $('#envsubmit') is occurring on page load, instead of when the "Create Environment" button is clicked and the HTML inserted. So as a result, there is no click function assigned to the Submit button, and it's acting off of default behavior.

Comment: use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the form submit handler.

Comment: I like your colleague - *rejecting your reality and substituting its own*.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle with this code in - http://jsfiddle.net/N4psS/2/. It works fine for me in Chrome (I get a POST to the path given). Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Ubuntu. It does the same with Firefox, and with Chrome on Windows. I'll keep playing. Thanks for the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably missing out the `event.preventDefault();`, and the form submits itself.
Use this instead :

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // whatever you want to do after submit();
})
```

Comment: ah, I do not. I'll try that.

Comment: didn't work, but I suspect I'm not providing enough context. I'll modify the question, above.